# Can not launch Python FastAPI project with Docker

Tags: python, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi, python-poetry

I am quite new to programming and have an error trying to lauch `fastapi` project with `Docker` and `Poetry`.

Here is my project structure:

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── domain
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── infrastructure
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── presentation
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── main.py
│   └── tests
│       └── __init__.py
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── README.md
```

Here is Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /backend

COPY . /backend

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install poetry
RUN poetry install

EXPOSE 8000
```

and docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:

  # PostgreSQL
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}'" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  # BackEnd
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
    command: bash -c 'uvicorn src.presentation.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

My `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "startup"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["RRoxxxsii <mishabur38@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
fastapi = {extras = ["all"], version = "^0.109.0"}
pytest="^7.4.4"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.23.3"
pre-commit = "^3.6.0"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.25"
alembic = "^1.13.1"
uvicorn = "^0.25.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I start the project with `docker compose up` I get the error:

`bash: line 1: uvicorn: command not found`

And I do not understand why, as I have `uvicorn` inside poetry.lock and pyproject.toml

Comment: Do you actually need Docker?  Python already has a couple of sophisticated tools for keeping a project's dependencies separate from the rest of the system; the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) might be a good starting point.  Using a tool like Poetry directly on the host will probably be easier than trying to wrap it in Docker, especially if you're new to all of these tools.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To be honest, I prefer to use Docker anyway. Despite the fact that using Docker is harder, it's much more intresting to dockerize all the dependencies (database, message brokers, etc.. and even python).

Comment: Is `uvicorn` in your `pyproject.toml`? Also you might want to use `./backend:/backend` as your volume in `docker-compose.yml` (not quite sure on this one though, but try it out).

Comment: @M.O. yes, sure, I have `uvicorn` in the `pyproject.toml`

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to reproduce this problem. It looks like you're simply missing a dependency. Could you include your `pyproject.toml` in the question? What is the output of the `poetry install` step in your Dockerfile? Does it show uvicorn getting installed?

Comment: @larsks I've just included the `toml` file to the question. When I start docker container I don't have installation steps shown in logs, I just get the error immediately

Comment: What does the build log for your container show? Does the packages get installed when you're building the container? What do you see if you ssh into the container? Have you tried using `poetry run uvicorn ..` to make poetry run the command from its environment?

Comment: It should be `command: bash -c 'poetry run uvicorn src.presentation.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload'`.

Comment: @sinoroc This way I get this error: `Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /backend or its parents`. I suppose I have problems with copying dirs from host machine to docker image in Dockerfile, but can't figure out where exactly I made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I tried to reproduce the above,

I think there are a few things here to point out,

1. Poetry related

   - 1a. poetry will look for a directory with the same name as the project name in the pyproject.toml file
     in this case it should be `startup/` under your `backend/` directory
   - 1b. poetry will also complain and fail to install the current project if it doesn't find a README.md under the `backend/` directory, in this case the root dir of the project "startup"
2. Docker related

   - In your compose file you have the host volume `.` mapped to container dir `/backend`, and on top of that you have `COPY . /backend`, I suspect this does a funny overwrite operation, although, I'm not 100% sure what happens there but someone more familiar with the docker mounting system would clarify it better than me.

However, I got around it by changing the workdir name to something other than `/backend` like `/service` in the below reproducible example

docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  # BackEnd
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
    command: bash -c 'poetry run uvicorn startup.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /service

COPY . /service

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install poetry
RUN poetry install

EXPOSE 8000
```

directory structure

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── README.md
│   └── startup
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── docker-compose.yaml
```